# Activity finish() not working when started from PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-pendingintent, foreground

In my application I have a foreground service that upon being pressed starts an Activity with the following PendingIntent

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    startForeground(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_ID, getNotification()); 
}

private Notification getNotification(){
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
  notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  ...

  return notification;
}
```

The Activity starts and everything works fine with it, however, when I call finish() it doesn't close the Activity although it is running the finish(); statement, I made sure using the debugger.

Comment: So, the activity comes to foreground. `finish()` gets called and it still stays in the foreground?

Comment: Exactly, the activity does not close

Comment: Are there any statements after the `finish()` call?

Comment: No, I'm even calling return; after finish()

Comment: Thats strange...if it isn't any bother...can you share the code for activity?

Comment: I don't believe the activity itself has anything to do, I just created and opened a dummy activity with a button that when pressed runs finish() and the result is the same.

Comment: How are you able to launch your activity without the `FLAG_ACIVITY_NEW_TASK`?

Comment: post your manifest. Are you sure you aren't starting the `Activity` twice? What happens if you press the button again? Does it then close? Also, you should use 'sdb shell dumpsys activity activities` which will show the activities in your task.